# Could someone please help me to add category id with in this query so this will return posts from a certain category?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Could someone please help me to add category id with in this query so this will return posts from a certain category? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php foreach(_get($wp_query->posts? : array()) as $n => $post){ setup_postdata($post); ?>

    // HTML and post Tags

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thats a very weird way to loop over posts, is there a particular reason you are looping over `$wp_query->posts` and aren't using a standard loop?

Comment: The company that I work with, they have set the standard to query this way :(

Comment: Ok, but... Where is the question? All you’ve said is what you want - but it’s not a wishing well, but Q&A site, so how can we help? (No, we won’t write it for you - it’s not a job board too)

Comment: @MahmudFarooque note that there are performance disadvantages as it immediately forces all `\WP_Post` instances to fetch all their data at the same time. It's also non-standard and doesn't fire a lot of the usual hooks.  I also see `_get` is not defined in your question

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I am really sorry for the way I expressed it. I have changed the title and content of my question. 
Thanks

Comment: @TomJNowell I am working on a custom theme framework that the company made with and I know there are lot of ways to do this and I got those solutions too yet I had to do it this way.

Comment: Hmm, but there is no query in your code. All it does is loop through global $wp_query, which is already processed...

Comment: So you’ll have to use pre_get_posts filter (based on where you do this loop) or create your own query and use it in this loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow proper wordpress method not follow someone's code or copy paste code.

```
 /*
 * CODEX: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters
 * Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp- 
 includes/query.php
 */
$args = array(

//////Category Parameters - Show posts associated with certain categories.
//http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters
 //all categories parameter 

'cat' => 5,//(int) - use category id.
'category_name' => 'staff, news',          //(string) - Display posts that 
  have these categories, using category slug.
'category_name' => 'staff+news',           //(string) - Display posts that 
 have "all" of these categories, using category slug.
'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ),         //(array) - use category id.
'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ),          //(array) - use category id.
'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ),      //(array) - use category id.
'post_type' => 'post', //post or you can use your custom post type 
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'date');

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   $the_query->the_post();
    // Do Stuff
  } // end while
} // endif
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and just provides a link, if billerickson.net ever goes down or changes the page, the answer becomes useless. Please take the relevant parts and embed them in your answer

Comment: Sure @TomJNowell i will take care this things in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it this way. Thanks everyone.

```
<?php
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'cat' => '8'
));
foreach(_get($q->posts? : array()) as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);?>

          // HTML and post Tags

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer if it does the job? Additionally explain what it was that fixed the issue

Comment: I'd also note that `'fields' => 'ids'` does not speed this up as `setup_postdata` will fetch the entire post anyway, causing lots of small queries to be made on each iteration around the loop